# vimのmatchitでhtml内の<script>の中で括弧に飛べなくなる

Tags: vim

vim7.4でmatchit(同梱版)プラグインを有効にすると
html内のタグの中のかっこで`%`を押しても、カーソルが飛びません。

なぜでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同梱版でしょうか？
そちらだとhtmlは飛べない可能性があります。

https://github.com/tmhedberg/matchit

こちらを試して貰えますか。

Answer (score 1):

matchit.vimでは、対応する括弧の組を`b:match_words`という変数で管理しています。
HTMLの場合、この変数に括弧が登録されていないようです。
HTMLファイルを開いた状態で、`:echo b:match_words`を実行して確認してみてください。

`.vimrc`に次のように書いておくと、どのようなファイルタイプでも`words`で指定した括弧の組が有効になります。

```
function! s:set_match_words()
  " Enable these pairs for all file types
  let words = ['(:)', '{:}', '[:]', '（:）', '「:」']
  if exists('b:match_words')
    for w in words
      if b:match_words !~ '\V' . w
        let b:match_words .= ',' . w
      endif
    endfor
  else
    let b:match_words = join(words, ',')
  endif
endfunction
augroup matchit-setting
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * call s:set_match_words()
augroup END
```

補足: 現状`b:match_words`にマルチバイト文字を指定すると、`d%`などは正しく動かないという問題があります。(https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/734)